# Trying to accessing my Firestore Observable in the HTML

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access my Firestore variable in the template but it's showing up empty. Does anyone have an idea on how to get this working?

**HTML**

```
<a class="header">{{submissions[0]?.UsersName}}</a>
```

**Typescript**

```
this.submissionsCollection = this.afs.collection(pathSubmissions);
this.submissions = this.submissionsCollection.valueChanges();

submissionsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Submission>;
submissions: Observable<Submission[]>;
```

Answer (score 0):

this gonna work :

```
<a class="header">{{(submissions| async )[0]?.UsersName}}</a>
```

if You want to use it inside an NgFor :

```
  <a *ngFor="let submission of submissions | async"> {{submission?.UsersName}} </a>
```

Comment: I tried your first solution. I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`. I'm certain there is a value there in my database.

Comment: I thinks you're getting null value from you're firestore. please show how you'are receiving data from firebase and make sure data is not null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a *ngIf="submissions | async as submission" class="header">{{submission[0].UsersName}}</a>
```

Comment: beware, i found some issues using this method. if you use same observable later on code eg: in ngFor, it will duplicate the result. i am not sure error is specific to me.